# Default grub entry not resetting

Tags: grub2, clonezilla

I have setup Clonezilla to automatically backup my system every 2 weeks; been successful for nearly a year now. In my script, I use these commands to get my system to reboot into the Clonezilla environment:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-reboot "Clonezilla Live (Unattended Backup)"
/bin/systemctl reboot
```

Since I have Clonezilla shutdown my machine after it's done, I didn't notice a problem until this morning. Instead of the default grub entry going back to my Mint 19.2 system, it was still stuck on the Clonezilla entry. Running `sudo update-grub` did not fix the problem; rebooting also did nothing.

I was able to fix this by deleting `/boot/grub/grubenv`, but this seems like a workaround as opposed to an actual fix. My current disk setup looks like this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   LABEL         SIZE FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT            UUID
sda                  477G                              
├─sda2                99M vfat   /boot/efi             F6CB-D0AC
├─sda5              47.7G btrfs  /mnt/timeshift/backup 2877dfa4-3adf-446b-8892-3b069e669003
├─sda6                 8G swap   [SWAP]                8b2eecf2-6f09-4355-a44b-bd2eb1d4de47
├─sda7 Linux-Home  413.9G ext4   /home                 773e8a83-cc23-4fc1-9663-fae584354445
└─sda8 Clonezilla    7.3G vfat                         A993-6742
```

Comment: Have you tried not using your script? Maybe the fail has to do with something related to it.

Comment: I'm going to try rebooting later tonight, just using the (2) aforementioned commands to see if that makes any difference. Since the issue first popped up after I reinstalled my system with BTRFS for /, it makes me wonder if that's the problem. I was given this link on another forum - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_grub_support_btrfs.3F - so I'm leaning that direction.

Comment: @guillermochamorro - I ran the commands without the script and the same thing happened, so I can only assume that BTRFS's issues with grub are the problem.